# How to get desired result in the final answer

Tags: python

I was making a code to find the number divisible by x in a certain range and for that this is the code I wrote:

```
num = int(input("Enter your number: "))

for i in range(1,301):
    if i % num == 0:
        print(i)
```

I was able to get the result, however then I wanted to get the final print in this format:

13 / 13 = 1

26 / 13 = 2

and so on for any number chosen by the user. Please guide me how to get the result that way.

Comment: What have you tried? Seems simple enough to do `print(f"{i} / {num} = {i / num}")`, no?

Comment: I was trying it via similar method that I used while I was making a code for multiplication, but it wasn't working for me. This helps, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
num = int(input("Enter your number: "))

for i in range(1,301):

    if i % num == 0:

       print(f"{i} / {num} = {int(i/num)}")
```

Comment: This is perfect, I would like to know the reason behind using f when writing the print command. Apologies if may questions are silly, I am a noob.

Answer (score 1):

- num divisible by i.

```py
num = int(input("Enter your number: "))

for i in range(1,301):

    if num % i == 0:
       
       print(f'{num} / {i} = {num//i}')
```

more about [f-strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer would look like this:

```
for i in range(1, 301):
    if i%num ==0:
        result = i/num
        print("%i/%i=%i"%(i,num,result))
```

You would just format the values inside the answer.

Comment: That works but it's an old and clunky way of doing it. Format fields are more standardised and way easier to understand